# show html table (via xtable) in knitr-powered document

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

I am trying to figure out how to use xtable when creating html pages with knitr.
My main reason to work with xtable is because I want to be able to rotate column names and/or rownames.
This is my .rmd document:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE} 
library(xtable)
data(tli)
tli.table <- xtable(tli[1:10,])
align(tli.table) <- "|r|r|lp{3cm}l|r|"
tt1 <- print(tli.table, rotate.rownames=TRUE,
             rotate.colnames=TRUE, type =   "html")
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'}
tt1
```
````

When I knit this document to html with `knit2html`, the row and column names are messed up and the html code is echoed as well. What am I doing wrong? (or is there a better way to construct nicely laid out html tables through knitr?)

Comment: Thanks, @Gregor, it's much better this way

Answer (score 3):

Peter, 
I am also frustrated with the odd behaviour of `xtable` when recreating tables that used to work before but not in the new `R Markdow v2` using `pandoc` for the conversion to html.

The most I could do with your table was make it render pretty but no local column alignment or column header rotation. To do this put all the code in one r chunk with the option `results='asis'`.

This worked for me using RStudio 0.98.1103, R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09), Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit), Running under: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS), knitr_1.9,    rmarkdown_0.5.1, and  xtable_1.7-4:

Since you mention using knit2html (not available for R 3.1.3) please try my code in your installation and see if it still works.
If so this might be a reason not to get latest versions just yet.

Using Knitr's `Kable` the headings appear consistent with the default alignment of right-justified for numeric columns and left-justified otherwise. Xtable's headings appear always to be centred and I can't find the option for changing this behaviour.

````
---
output:
html_document:
   self_contained: false
   theme: flatly
   keep_md: true
---
<style type="text/css">
table { max-width: 200%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; }
th {    background-color: #000000;
        color: #ffffff;
        width: 2.5cm; }
td {    background-color: #dcdcdc }
</style>

```{r, echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'}
library(xtable)
data(tli)
tli.table <- xtable(tli[1:10,])
align(tli.table) <- "|r|r|lp{3cm}l|r|"
print(tli.table,
      rotate.rownames=F,
      rotate.colnames=F,
      type="html",
      include.rownames = F)
```

```{r via kable, echo=FALSE, results='markup'}
require(knitr)
kable(tli.table, format = "html", 
      padding = 0, 
      row.names=F,
      caption = "Via kable")
```
````